# No able to Retrieve Custom attibute value of a catgeory in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, custom

I have created a custom attribute for my category. 
Below is my code.
In InstallData.php

```
<?php
/* file: app/code/Atwix/CategoryAttribute/Setup/InstallData.php */

   namespace Vidushi\KeyFeature\Setup;

  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
  use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
  use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
/**
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Category::ENTITY,
        'keyfeature_1',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Key Feature 1',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Category::ENTITY,
        'keyfeature_2',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Key Feature 2',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Category::ENTITY,
        'keyfeature_3',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Key Feature 3',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );
}
```

}

An in category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- file: app/code/Atwix/CategoryAttribute/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml    -->

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="Key_Features">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Key Features</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="keyfeature_1">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Key Feature 1</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
     <field name="keyfeature_2">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Key Feature 2</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
     <field name="keyfeature_3">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Key Feature 3</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Now i am trying to get this value as

```
<?php 
                         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                         $PCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load(185);
                          //here get your attribute
                         ?>
                        <div><?php echo $PCategory->getKeyFeature1(); ?></div>
```

But this is not working,
i am not getting what will come $PCategory->getKeyFeature1(); in place of getKeyFeature1(); i think this is wrong. Can anyone give me correct name based on my above code

Comment: Try to get like this <?php echo $PCategory->getKeyfeature1(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code

```
    $categoryId = 185
    $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
    $categoryData = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $getCategoryTitle1 = $categoryData->getData('keyfeature_1');
```

hope this will help you

Comment: No. Its not working. It appears blank

Comment: You have to use store wise for category attribute value.

Comment: @ChiragParmar Can u please explain

Comment: Answer is already given by Msquare @Nafisa

Comment: @ChiragParmar Can u plz guide. the problem still not resolved

Comment: Ok.. Just wait. I am posting one image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105481/discussion-between-chirag-parmar-and-nafisa).

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid use of  ObjectManager

```
protected $_storeManager;

protected $_categoryNameFactory;


public function __construct(
    ...........................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryNameFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...........................................
)
{
    ...........................................
    $this->_categoryNameFactory = $categoryNameFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...........................................
}


public function getCategoryName($categoryId)
{
    $category = $this->_categoryNameFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
    //echo $category->getKeyfeature1();
    //echo $category->getKeyfeature2();
    //echo  $category->getKeyfeature3();
    // exit();
    return $category;
}
```

Call in your phtml

```
$categoryId = 12;
$data = $block->getCategoryName($categoryId);
print_r($data->getData()); // update this
```

> your **getKeyfeature3** is wrong only first and after _( underscore ) character is Uppercase. remianing is lowercase

***Note: please use  varible name without digit for best utilization.***

Comment: $category->getKeyfeature1(); this still does not work for me

Comment: it may be value is not present for that  particular category or check your store view is different. check it to print your category collection like print_r($data->getData()); and find your atribute name and value.

Comment: getting this error Error filtering template: Type Error occurred when creating object: Amasty\Shopby\Block\Product\ProductList\ChildrenCategoryList

Comment: disable unused module temparary for check your attribute value. php bin/magento module:d VendoreName_ModuleName

Comment: when i do print_r($data) it gives me error Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1608519680 bytes) in /var/www/wazoodl/public_html/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Amasty_Shopby/templates/product/productlist/children_category_list.phtml on line 73

Comment: i cant increase the memory limit

Comment: check update in answer

Comment: what have u updated? print_r($data->getData());  also did not work

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Catalog -> Categories -> Select any category`

Now click on `Scope:All Store Views`

You can find many stores here. Now save it one by one.

[image]

Comment: It is stored store wise only. still not able to retrieve its vale